# Installing WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 as a windows service has servletException

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

After installing (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service) and starting WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 as a windows service, there is an exception when opening page of view roles from users page as below,
[image: Role View]

[image: Error]

Then popup blank page,

[image: blank page]

However, this error does not happen if I use wso2server.bat running in command console. The same issue happens to WSO2 AM 1.10.0 as well.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding below line to `wrapper.conf`

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```

This is mentioned in [Identity Server Docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service). I reopened [a WSO2 Document JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-3109) about this.